# Проблема с cog'ами Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Написал Discord бота через Visual Studio Code с помощью GPT. Когда дело дошло до разделения команд бота через cog`и, начали появляться ошибки. Помогите, пожалуйста, найти и исправить ошибку, GPT бесполезен. Прошу простить за очень длинный текст...

**Код из основного файла main.py:**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import json
import asyncio
from typing import Dict

with open('config.json', 'r') as f:
    config: Dict[str, str] = json.load(f)

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=config['prefix'], intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Бот {bot.user.name} ONLINE и готов выполнять команды!')
    await bot.load_extension('cogs.autodelete_cog')

bot.run(config['token'])
```

**Код из файла autodelete_cog.py:**

```
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
import asyncio

class autodeleteCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.delete_bot_messages.start()

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.channel.id == 1020805451690037290: # id канала
            if message.author == self.bot.user:
                await asyncio.sleep(10)
                await message.delete()
                return

            member_roles = [role.name for role in message.author.roles]
            if "Владелец" in member_roles or "Чёткий чел" in member_roles:
                return

            if message.content.startswith("1") and not message.attachments:
                await message.delete()
                await message.channel.send(f"{message.author.mention}, ваше сообщение удалено, потому что оно отправлено не по форме.")
            elif not message.content.startswith("1") and not message.attachments:
                await message.delete()
                await message.channel.send(f"{message.author.mention}, ваше сообщение удалено, потому что оно отправлено не по форме.")
            elif not message.content.startswith("1") and any(attachment.url.lower().endswith(('.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.mp4', '.mov')) for attachment in message.attachments):
                await message.delete()

    @tasks.loop(seconds=10)
    async def delete_bot_messages(self):
        async for message in self.bot.get_channel(1020805451690037290).history(limit=200):
            if message.author == self.bot.user and message.content.startswith("ваше сообщение удалено, потому что оно отправлено не по форме."):
                await message.delete()

    @commands.command()
    async def start_deletion(self, ctx):
        self.delete_bot_messages.start()
        await ctx.send("Начало автоматического удаления сообщений.")

    @commands.command()
    async def stop_deletion(self, ctx):
        self.delete_bot_messages.stop()
        await ctx.send("Автоматическое удаление сообщений остановлено.")

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(autodeleteCog(bot))
```

**Запускаю main.py, бот работает но выдаёт такие ошибки:**

```
C:\DISCORD BOT\cogs\autodelete_cog.py:47: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'BotBase.add_cog' was never awaited
  bot.add_cog(autodeleteCog(bot))
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
2023-08-15 22:29:53 ERROR    discord.client Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\DISCORD BOT\venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 947, in _load_from_module_spec
    await setup(self)
TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\DISCORD BOT\venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 441, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\DISCORD BOT\main.py", line 17, in on_ready
    await bot.load_extension('cogs.autodelete_cog')
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\DISCORD BOT\venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 1013, in load_extension
    await self._load_from_module_spec(spec, name)
  File "C:\DISCORD BOT\venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 952, in _load_from_module_spec
    raise errors.ExtensionFailed(key, e) from e
discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionFailed: Extension 'cogs.autodelete_cog' raised an error: TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression
```

[image: Фотография]

Comment: попробуй `await bot.add_cog(autodeleteCog(bot))`
Ну и сделай метод setup async